# How to run EMBOSS in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, software-installation

I have a question that will maybe look naive for you, but I need to use the EMBOSS GUI in order to help me to do some work.
I've followed the installing instructions:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install emboss
```

Terminal tells me that the package is successfully installed, but I've got no idea of where I can run the program from. And I haven't found any instructions to do that in any page online.
I've looked for a launcher or something in all the folders but can't find anything like that.
Is there something I missed to do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that EMBOSS itself includes a GUI? maybe you need a separate package such as `jemboss` (*"Jemboss is a Graphical User Interface (GUI) to EMBOSS, the European Molecular Biology Open Software Suite"*)